# KendoUI Multiselect deselect event is not binded properly in jquery

Tags: kendo-ui

I tried to bind the 'deselect' event to the KendoUI multiselect control using jquery. But seems like it is not firing: Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function multiselect_deselect(e) {
        debugger;
        if (e.item.context.localName == 'li') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }   
    var multiselectCtrl = $("#enterFeedbackForm_" + '@ContextId' + " #FeedbackCategoryList_" + '@ContextId').data("kendoMultiSelect");
    multiselectCtrl.bind("deselect", multiselect_deselect);
});
```

the debugger point does not hit. We're using Kendo UI Kendo UI v2015.2.703

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think kendo-ui has a bound property for this already. If you take a look at the [event documentation](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/events), it shows you how to bind the events on initialization of kendo ui multiselect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function onDeselect(e) {
        debugger;
        if (e.item.context.localName == 'li') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };

    var data = [
        { text: "Africa", value:"1" },
        { text: "Europe", value:"2" },
        { text: "Asia", value:"3" },
        { text: "North America", value:"4" },
        { text: "South America", value:"5" },
        { text: "Antarctica", value:"6" },
        { text: "Australia", value:"7" }
    ];

    $("#select").kendoMultiSelect({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: data,
        deselect: onDeselect,
    });
});
```

Comment: Than you Sir...I will look into it.

Comment: No problem, ask if you need help with implementing it:)